# highlighting: match dot in group

Tags: syntax-highlighting, regular-expression, highlight

I have several `syntax match` patterns, that logically belong together.

Currently I match them like this:
`syntax match FOO /\v<(foo1|foo2|foo3)>/`

What I actually want to match is `.foo1`, `.foo2` and `.foo3`. Here lies my problem: I cannot get the pattern to match the additional dot.

Here are some of my tries:

- `/\v<(\.foo1|\.foo2|\.foo3)>/`
- `/\v<(.foo1|.foo2|.foo3)>/`
- `/\.foo1|\.foo2|\.foo3)>/`
- `/v<\(\.foo1|\.foo2|.foo3\)>/`
- `/<(.foo1|.foo2|.foo3\)>/`

And many more of similar combinations. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`|` separates atoms and dot makes vim unhappy about it so you could add additional braces `syntax match FOO /\v(\.foo1>)|(\.foo2>)|(\.foo3>)/` or put a dot out of the branching:

```
syntax match FOO /\v\.<(foo1|foo2|foo3)>/
hi link FOO Statement
```

[image]

Comment: Your second suggestion works as intended! Thank you. I'd prefer your first solution, which only works partially for me: everything gets matched, but not the first entry (`.foo1`). However if I add any other string before, `.foo1` will get matched. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: `syntax match FOO /\v(\.foo1>)|(\.foo2>)|(\.foo3>)/` should also work.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a lot! This has been annoying me for quite some time :)